# Passport.js positive result

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

I am attempting to authenticate a user in a Node app using Sequelize and Passport. I am able to hit my database but can't seem to get a positive result. Basically, I have a simple frontend form that accepts a username and password (using the respective names "username" and "password") and then the following Passport definition:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(
  {usernameField: 'email'},
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      models.TeacherX.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
       if (err) { return done(err); }
       if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
       if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user);
       });
    }
));
```

Then I call it with:

```
router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login?msg=failure'}),
    function(req, res) {
      res.redirect("/?msg=positive");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the request to the verify callback, you need to set the property `passReqToCallback` to `true` or remove the `req` param from the verify callback. Try this:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(
  {passReqToCallback: true ,
   usernameField: 'email'},
  function(req, email, password, done) {
      models.TeacherX.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
       if (err) { return done(err); }
       if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
       if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user);
      });
  }
));
```